# Is there a way to find the book's circulation numbers?

Tags: publishing, book, printing, isbn

Usually it's on a special info page before the title page/near the cover, but I can't find it for the book I have. I want to know, if possible, exactly how many were *printed*.

Edit: The book's ISBN 10: 2909808742 / 2909808858, ISBN 13: 9782909808741

Comment: This information is usually not publicly available. There are companies like Nielsen that you can pay to get sales figures collected from a number of book sellers, but publishers rarely disclose their print run.

Comment: @what , too bad. I'm just used to the vast majority of books I had, having this info. Then again, they were published in different (to the book in question) country and also are mostly of different genre.

Comment: @what: IMHO, questions about publishing and the publishing industry are on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on the book, publisher, and the time it is printed. It can be that the page does not even exists or the info is not available. If you can provide the Title, Author, Year of print, it has some chance to get it looked for.

Comment: Added ISBNs to the question.

Answer (score 1):

For Russian books the print-run is always listed on the copyright page.

Comment: I doubt it would be russian published book: 'Giovanna Garzoni: Natures Mortes'

Comment: Yep. Quite convenient and I got used to it, but the book in question is not Russian.

Comment: @DanM. Right, I thought it was a general question; hence my answer.